# Debian 9: Postfix Blocking from headerchecks the regexp: $800/week

Tags: regular-expression, postfix

How can I block the word $800/week from the regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks in Postfix 3.3.2.

I've tried multiple times and can't get postmap to find it during -q

Comment: Perhaps you can show some of those attempts, so that answerers can explain what was wrong? Seeing the `$` immediately makes me wonder if that's accidentally trying to match the end of the line somewhere.

Comment: Currently have 
/\*800\week\// REJECT You've warned, and now blacklisted